# No public static parameters method with Galen

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot, galen

In a project in which I'm working, I'm trying to use Galen without TestNG (so, the JUnit based version).

This is the code that I have for the sample class that I've made:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.galenframework.support.GalenJavaTestBase;
import com.galenframework.testng.GalenTestNgTestBase;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.Extension;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import com.galenframework.junit.GalenJUnitTestBase;

public class GalenTesting extends GalenJUnitTestBase {

    @Override

    public WebDriver createDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        return driver;
    }

    @Test
    public void welcomePage_shouldLookGood_onDesktopDevice() throws IOException {
        super.load("http://www.google.com", 1024, 768);
        super.checkLayout("/specs/welcomePage.spec", Arrays.asList("mobile"));
    }
```

Which is pretty much the code that can be found in the Galen doc for Java usage.
I am having an issue with running this code, because it states that:

```
java.lang.Exception: No public static parameters method on class it.automationTest.GalenTesting

    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.getParametersMethod(Parameterized.java:299)
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.<init>(Parameterized.java:246)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Process finished with exit code -1
```

At first, I thought it was referring to the methods' calls inside the "welcomePage_shouldLookGood_onDesktopDevice()" method, so I've inserted a super.methodName() to try fix that but it didn't work. 
I've also tried to read the source code of all the superclasses but I couldn't find anything useful that could help me preventing this Exception.
Could someone point me in the right direction?

### EDIT

As requested, this is the updated version of the code. 
It now contains an iterable method for the Test Devices (as kindly pointed out hypery2k).
The **original question** is solved, because there createDriver() method was annotated just with @Overriden, while it should have been only with a @Test annotation. Now I'm facing the following issue, for which first I'll put the new updated code, then the stack error.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;


import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import com.galenframework.junit.GalenJUnitTestBase;

public class GalenTesting extends GalenJUnitTestBase {

WebDriver driver;

public GalenTesting() {
    super();

}

@Override
public WebDriver createDriver() {
    createDriverVoid();
    return driver;
}

@Test
public void createDriverVoid() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@Test
public void welcomePage_shouldLookGood_onDesktopDevice() throws IOException {
    super.load("http://www.google.com", 1024, 768);
    super.checkLayout("/specs/welcomePage.spec", Arrays.asList("mobile"));
}

@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Iterable<Object[]> devices() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{// @formatter:off
            {new TestDevice("desktop", new Dimension(1024, 800), Arrays.asList("normal", "desktop"))},
            {new TestDevice("fullhd", new Dimension(1920, 1080), Arrays.asList("fullhd", "desktop"))},// @formatter:on
    });
}


}
```

The class is now giving the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching createDriver with any parameter from org.junit.runner.Request$1@2d6a9952

    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Process finished with exit code -1
```

I've been trying to mess around with some methods that I've added (like the constructor that calls the super()) but it still gives the same error. It returns the same error even with the original fixed code.

Answer (score 1):

your missing the Parameters for your test case, see [here](https://github.com/hypery2k/galen_samples/blob/master/junit/src/test/java/sample/util/GalenBaseTest.java#L98) for my complete example:

```
@Parameters
public static Iterable<Object[]> devices() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{// @formatter:off
            {new TestDevice("small-phone", new Dimension(280, 800), asList("small-phone", "phone", "mobile"))},
            {new TestDevice("normal-phone", new Dimension(320, 800), asList("normal-phone", "phone", "mobile"))},
            {new TestDevice("big-phone", new Dimension(380, 800), asList("big-phone", "phone", "mobile"))},
            {new TestDevice("small-tablet", new Dimension(450, 800), asList("small-tablet", "tablet", "mobile"))},
            {new TestDevice("normal-tablet", new Dimension(450, 800), asList("normal-tablet", "tablet", "mobile"))},
            {new TestDevice("desktop", new Dimension(1024, 800), asList("normal", "desktop"))},
            {new TestDevice("fullhd", new Dimension(1920, 1080), asList("fullhd", "desktop"))},// @formatter:on
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It now says this "java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching createDriver with any parameter"

Comment: can you post your test class again? I think you habe @Test on the createDriver method

Comment: Hi @hypery2k, just added!

Comment: please remove the test annotation at createDriverVoid

Comment: Same error if I try to remove @Test at createDriverVoid

Comment: did you run the test only from IDEA? Can you try from the command line?

Comment: the CLI just throws a lot of errors. Yes, I can try only via IDEA

Answer (score 0):

As you are using **`JUnit`** based **`Galen`** framework, I would recommend 2 quick changes as follows:

- Change the `@Override` Annotation into **`@Test`** Annotation or to a valid one.
- Change `crome` to **`chrome`** within **`"webdriver.crome.driver"`**

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! 1) The @Override notation is mandatory, as I'm extending a class with an abstract method (or, even if I change it with something else, it won't fix the issue); 2) Thanks: I didn't noticed that typo but it didn't fix the issue